# What did a "don't-issue-rulings" semicha (ordination) look like?

Tags: halacha, rabbis, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, moshe-feinstein, semicha

Again from the biography of Rabbi Moshe Feinstein found in *Igrot Moshe* Volume 8 (emphasis added):

> Many approached [him] for ordination, and he was not difficult on them. Some ordinations were anticipatory, in the hope the student would later be fit for issuing rulings *(psak)*; some were a matter of honor, for those who had studied a great deal and needed something to show for it; **some included written instructions not to ever issue a ruling**.

What would that type look like? ("The semicha that wasn't?"). Was that caveat in the original document, or a second one?

(And would anyone who held one of these confess to doing so?)

Comment: I've heard that the new Igros Moshe has text of the Smicha he used to give.

Comment: What is the point of Semikhah (talmud torah) if it is not lilmod ul'lamed and lishmor v'laasot?  Learning and teaching for what purpose?  Halachah lemaaseh is the ikar of talmud torah.

Comment: The first smicha I received said on it "Yoreh Yoreh" however at the end the Rov ended off that only after receiving shimush may I be accepted as a "Rov U'Moreh Horah". I later asked the Rov who determines this and when does this come to be. How much shimush, etc. He said the learning is of course a lifetime process, but the ability to pasken will simply eventually come with enough experience. I made shimush and continued to do so until this day and later received another (more "chashuv") smicha that says "v'yochol l'haros b'issur v'heter v'shar halachos"

Answer (score 4):

I think that the source of this concept - a Semicha with a caveat -  is in the Yerushalmi Chagiga [Perek 1 Halacha 8 (Daf 7a Vilna edition)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14138&st=&pgnum=562).

First it dsicusses that one can give a *limited* Semicha, then in the 2nd wide line:

> מהו למנות זקינים לימים? נישמעינה מן הדא:  ר׳ חייה בר בא אתא לגבי רבי לעזר אמר ליה פייס לי לרבי יורן נשייא דיכתוב
> לי חדא איגרא דאיקר ניפוק לפרנסתי לארעא ברייתא. פיים ליה וכתב ליה
> הרי שילחנו אליכם אדם גדול שלוחינו וכיוצא בנו עד שהוא מגיע אצלינו.‏

A *time based* Semicha, valid until he comes back to us.

> ר׳ חזקיה' ר׳ דוסתי, ר׳ אבא בר זמינא ומטו בה משמיה דר׳ דוסי םבא: הכין כתב ליה *הרי שילחנולכם אדם גדול*  ומה הוא גדולתו? שאינו בוש לומר "לא שמעתי".‏

A Semicha with a caveat: that he is able to say *I dont know!*.

The Rambam seems to Pasken this in [הלכות סנהדרין והעונשין המסורים להם - פרק רביעי](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02038.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2):

> ח וְיֵשׁ לָהֶן לְמַנּוֹת כָּל מִי שֶׁיִּרְצוּ לִדְבָרִים יְחִידִים. וְהוּא שֶׁיִּהְיֶה רָאוּי לְכָל הַדְּבָרִים. כֵּיצַד. חָכָם מֻפְלָא שֶׁרָאוּי לְהוֹרוֹת לְכָל הַתּוֹרָה כֻּלָּהּ **יֵשׁ לְבֵית דִּין לִסְמֹךְ אוֹתוֹ וְלִתֵּן לוֹ רְשׁוּת לָדוּן וְלֹא לְהוֹרוֹת בְּאִסּוּר וְהֶתֵּר**. אוֹ יִתְּנוּ לוֹ רְשׁוּת בְּאִסּוּר וְהֶתֵּר וְלֹא לָדוּן דִּינֵי מָמוֹנוֹת. אוֹ יִתְּנוּ רְשׁוּת לָזֶה וְלָזֶה אֲבָל לֹא לָדוּן דִּינֵי קְנָסוֹת. אוֹ לָדוּן דִּינֵי קְנָסוֹת אֲבָל לֹא לְהַתִּיר בְּכוֹרוֹת בְּמוּמִין. אוֹ יִתְּנוּ לוֹ רְשׁוּת לְהַתִּיר נְדָרִים בִּלְבַד אוֹ לִרְאוֹת כְּתָמִים. וְכֵן כָּל כַּיּוֹצֵא בָּהֶן:‏
>
> ט וְכֵן יֵשׁ לַסּוֹמְכִין לִתֵּן רְשׁוּת עַד זְמַן וְלוֹמַר לַנִּסְמָךְ יֵשׁ לְךָ רְשׁוּת לָדוּן אוֹ לְהוֹרוֹת עַד שֶׁיָּבוֹא הַנָּשִׂיא לְכָאן. אוֹ כָּל זְמַן שֶׁאֵין אַתָּה עִמָּנוּ בַּמְּדִינָה. וְכֵן כָּל כַּיּוֹצֵא בָּזֶה:‏